# How to get branch name in log?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

How to get branch name by its color in TortoiseGit log for "All Branches" option? Or how to get branch name some commit belongs to in TortoiseGit or Git?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options:

1. The most progressive way: Select the commit and open the context menu and click on "Show branches this commit is on" which basically invokes `git branch -a --contains <commit>` right now.
2. Select the commit and then select "Branch" or "Parent 1" in the upper right and hit the up botton next to the combo box until you find the branch label.

Comment: Thanks: 1st works (do not know how I've missed that). 2nd is not clear: up green button? It does not go to label, goes to merge with other branch for me.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich Yeah, the green up button. It can be used to go up/down regarding the walk strategy selected in the drop down box.

Answer (score 1):

Have no idea about TortoiseGit.. but in git console you can use:

```
git branch --contains <commit>
```

Comment: Returns nothing to me. Branch could be remote.

Comment: may be u can do "get fetch -all" first and then run this command

Comment: No, need to use: `git.exe branch -a --contains ` - watched this in TortoiseGit on  "Show branches this commit is on" menu command.